# How to get value of nested object using array of keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have the following object:

```
interface Colors {
  [key: string]: Colors | string
}

const colors: Colors = {
  light: {
    gray: '#aaa',
  },
  black: '#000',
}
```

The problem is that i need to check if the passed `string` value represents some color in `colors` object like that:

```
// input
const color = 'light-gray'

// what I already done to get the array of keys
const keys = color.split('-') // ['light', 'gray']

// how to check if `keys` are in `colors` object

// expected output: true
```

I already tried the following:

```
keys.every(key => key in colors) // key: light -> true, key: gray -> false
```

Basically I'm looking for something like this:

```
const lightGray = colors[...keys] // unfortunatelly won't work
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "simple" iterative version:

```js
const findColor = (color) => {
  const colors = {
    light: {
      gray: '#aaa',
    },
    black: '#000',
  };

  // what you've already done to get the array of keys
  const keys = color.split('-') // ['light', 'gray']

  // loop through the object

  let box = colors;

  for (let i = 0; box != null && i < keys.length; ++i) {
    box = box[keys[i]];
  }

  return box;
}

console.log(findColor('light-gray'));
console.log(findColor('light-black'));
```

If you're comfortable with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), this could become:

```js
const findColor = (color) => {
  const colors = {
    light: {
      gray: '#aaa',
    },
    black: '#000',
  };

  // what you've already done to get the array of keys
  const keys = color.split('-') // ['light', 'gray']

  // use the keys to "open" colors

  const opener = (box, key) => {
    if (box == null) {
      return null; // avoid null[key]
    }

    return box[key];
  }

  return keys.reduce(opener, colors);
}

console.log(findColor('light-gray'));
console.log(findColor('light-black'));
```

Comment: Thanks, really nice and simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get for that, e.g.

```js
// returns #aaa
_.get(colours, 'light-gray'.split('-'))
```